# Can't format title properly for a plot in matlab

Tags: matlab

currently I'm creating a plot in matlab and pretty much have it complete, except that I can't figure out how to properly format a certain part of the title.

```
clc;
clear all;
n = 0:4;
T = 1/100;
y = (1/1000).^(n*T).*cos(200*pi*(n*T));
subplot(1,1,1);
stem(n,y);
xlabel('Sample Number, $$n$$','interpreter','latex');
ylabel('$$y[n]$$','interpreter','latex');
title('$$y[n]=(1/1000)^(n/100)\cos(200/pi nT)$$','interpreter','latex');
```

Now, most of it appears correctly, but the exponent of the (1/1000) part is not appearing correctly.  Instead of the entire (n/100) appearing over the fraction, only the first parenthesis is.  How should I go about correcting this so that the entire n/100 appears over the fraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brace should fix it.

```
title('$$y[n]=(1/1000)^{(n/100)}\cos(200/pi nT)$$','interpreter','latex');
```